# Is "such" ever used instead of "this/that" or "the said" in legal English?

Tags: word-usage, legalese, maltese-english

"*Such*" has many meanings, one of them being to refer to something of a particular kind/type (see "*[of this or that kind](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/such)"*).

However, in many legal documents and laws in Malta, "*such*" is used instead of "*this*" or "*that*", or instead of "*the said thing*". For example, a legal document might read as follows:

> The following are the terms and conditions regulating the relationship between A and B. **Such** terms and conditions are....

Here, "*such*" is not used to mean "*of this or that kind*", but is used instead of "*these*" (the terms and conditions previously mentioned).

Is this use of "*such*" limited to the legal English used in Malta or is this a common feature of the legal English used in the UK, USA and countries where English is an official language?

Comment: You can use it in other contexts, it's just not common. It sounds overly formal.

Comment: "Legalese" has many styles like this, which I think tend to come from older writing style that has been perpetuated by the profession.

Comment: *such* is not restricted to formal contexts and has plenty of colloquial uses.  *You gave a teacher the finger and started a food fight in the cafeteria. Dude, how long do you expect to get away with such sh_t?*

Comment: When used adjectivally it means "of that kind, of that nature".  I would like to see the full sentence where you think it means something else.

Comment: You could find something like this:  "Seller agrees to deliver six tons of fertilizer and Buyer agrees to pay for said fertilizer in one lump sum within five business days of delivery, such terms being contingent upon delivery of the full six tons occurring on or before April 15th of this calendar year."  *such* does  indeed refer to the aforementioned;  but **such** is not a pronoun there, and is not a proxy; it *alludes* to the terms as *quid-pro-quo*.  *A quid-pro-quo of that nature/structure*

Comment: Is Maltese law conducted in English, or is the xample a translation?

Comment: In English @RobbieGoodwin